# Comparing two cells every nth row via Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements, compare

I am looking to create conditional formatting rules which compare two sets of text to see if they match, highlighting the second entry red if they do not.  The content is being manually entered on the second row and we have 3 rows in between which is creating a problem.  I am only comparing Text2 to Text1, Text 4 to Text 3, etc.

Text1

Text2

3 Rows

Text3

Text4

(Pattern repeats for 500 entries)

I haven't found a way to do this with a single rule (if you know this would be awesome!) so I had a thought to use a macro to create a new rule for each comparison and repeat it the required number of times.

```
Range("J2").Select
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 250

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="J1=J2"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Select
Next i
```

End Sub

The main problem is the rows in between so I can't create a single conditional formatting formula and copy down.  The problem with my VBA code is Formula1 is hardcoded.  It should compare J1=J2, then J6=7, etc.

Anyone know a good solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean there are three _pairs_ of rows between each pair of texts you want to compare (that's the only way I can get J1=J2 then J9=J10)?

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo.  Should read "J1=J2, then J6=7"  It is 3 rows not pairs of rows, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a rule like this starting from J2:

```
=AND(J2<>J1,MOD(ROW(),5)=2)
```

[image]

If starting conditional formatting from a different row (say start formatting from J3 and compare it to J2, then compare J8 to J7) you could generalise it to:

```
=AND(J2<>J3,MOD(ROW()-ROW(J$3),5)=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  I managed to find a way to incorporate VBA code into Formula1 and used integers to change the value for each selection.  My actual data started on F5 so I used that as the initial cell selection.

```
Sub CondForm_Col_F()
'
' TestOne Macro
'
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    n = 4
    m = 5
Range("F5").Select
For i = 1 To 147
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=F" & m & "<>F" & n & ""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
n = n + 5
m = m + 5
ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Select
Next i
End Sub
```